# Select random values from two vector (python)

Tags: python, arrays, random

I have two vectors

```
   A
   B
```

which are coupled, I mean that they define a certain scalar field at a given position.

I want to select 1000 random items from A and plot them versus other the other 1000 B coupled items.

With this code

```
  A_rand=random.sample(A,1000)
```

I select 1000 random values of A. For example they are A[1],A[50],A[49], etc.

How can I select B[1],B[50],B[49],etc. ?

I tried

```
 B_rand=B[(A==A_rand)]
```

but it returned just one value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select indexes, not items:

```
rand = random.sample(range(len(A)), 1000)
```

Then you can use `A[rand[i]]` and `B[rand[i]]`.

For all selected items:

```
A_rand = [A[x] for x in rand]
B_rand = [B[x] for x in rand]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also couple them in beforehand with `zip` and then select the sample,

```
rand = random.sample(zip(A, B), 1000)
```

that way you will have a list with tuples.

For example `[(A[1],B[1]),(A[50],B[50]),(A[49],B[49]),...]`

Then to get `A_rand` and `B_rand` from that list you can unzip them with

```
A_rand, B_rand = zip(*rand)
```